# Get child panels of a panel in WeifenLuo 2.5.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dockpanel-suite

I want to create several DockContent s to my window at runtime. Also all contents should be visible to the user at the same time. I only want to add contents to the top and bottom side. So how do I add contents in which all contents have nearly the same size?

The problem I have now is the size of each content. Every time I add a content it gets smaller and smaller but the previous contents keep there size. This means it just split every time the same content to add another content.

To solve the problem I'm trying to check first if the DockPanel contains a DockPanel.Contents where DockState is DockState.Document. If not I add it as the first content. If it exists I want to check the contents child-panes if there is one that is docked at top. To access the child-panes I try it with IDockContent.DockHandler.Pane.NestedPanesContainer.NestedPanes. Unfortunately this doesn't seems to return only the childs of this pane but all existing panes.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. For this I used the "Pane.NestedPanesContainer.NestedPanes" to get all elements in the tree. And then build the tree with the property "Pane.NestedDockingStatus.PreviousPane" to get their parent nodes. This works fine but needs to be calculated each time. In my case it's fast enough.

Be careful what elements "NestedPanes" contains. The "DockPanel" can contain more than one tree. The property "DockContentHandler.DockState" determines in which tree it is.